# Chromecast receiver app on remote server

Tags: heroku, chromecast

does anyone know if its possible to host the receiver app for chromecast in a remote host, such as heroku? Is it only possible to find my chromecast device if its in the same wi-fi network?

Answer (score 0):

You've got two separate questions here.

1) Yes, the receiver app can be hosted anywhere, and the vast majority of them are on a remote host rather than served locally. When you register your app with the Chromecast SDK console, you will have to submit, with the appID, the URL where the receiver app is located. Keep in mind that if your app is 'published' (available to all rather than just to those Chromecasts you whitelist), then your host much be https:// enabled, whether it's local or remote.

2) I think you're asking whether or not a sender app can find a device that's not on the same wi-fi network? Generally, no ... but at Google I/O this summer they did discuss a feature that would allow people not on the network but close enough to the Chromecast (i.e. in the same room) to communicate.

If I'm misunderstanding question two, please clarify.

Comment: Actually I should have researched more before I asked this questio, my bad.
I could achieve what I wanted at that time.
I`ve built a sender app and receiver app, and hosted both in Heroku.
Now from a computer that is in the same network that chromecast is, I can communicate to chromecast via this remote apps.
Thank you for the answer! Is there some discussion online about this feature you mentioned? Sounds really interesting.